# SCSS - how to write multiple classes with & in one html tag

Tags: css, sass

I want to rewrite some vuetify rules and I want to change background of button to some other color. I can change this with SASS variables builded in vuetify by default but I am curious how to write this selector is SCSS using &

```
.v-btn {
  text-transform: initial;
  &.v-btn--disabled.v-btn--has-bg {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6) !important;
    color: var(--v-text-light-base) !important;
  }
}
```

`.v-btn` is repeated 3 times and is there any way to write something like this?

```
.v-btn {
  text-transform: initial;
  &.&--disabled.&--has-bg {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6) !important;
    color: var(--v-text-light-base) !important;
  }
}
```

& works with whitespaces `&--disabled &--has-bg` between classes but I need to connect multiple classes into one html element. Is there any way to build this using `&` ?

Comment: &#{&}--disabled#{&}--has-bg

Comment: Perfect ;) Add is as an answer, Thank you

Comment: Well, you can accept mikesteeghs answer if you want. I think a comment was enough. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign & to a variable so you can re-use this variable in the class name. This is what you get:

```
.v-btn {
  $self: &;
  text-transform: initial;

  #{$self}.#{$self}--disabled.#{$self}--has-bg {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6) !important;
    color: var(--v-text-light-base) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as Amaury Hanser mentioned in comment you can omit self and write & directly, Thanks for help